# Weird Files and Folders

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I have a folder in the Lubuntu which has following structure:

```
soprano (4,2 KB)
.ecryptfs (26,8 GB) - *this folder was hidden*
lost+found (16 KB)
```

**Inside the folder `.ecryptfs`:**

```
soprano
```

**And inside the `soprano` has:**

```
.Private (26,8GB)
.ecryptfs (4,1KB)
```

**Inside the folder `.Private`:**

Has thirty folder, with genre names `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZvWTNIrxgWSURD` and files with genre names `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZvWTNIrxgWSURD.c6GzJjBSTpPKX0MXUeFVD-aTDzlxJi8CTnZwtWk2U--`

**In turn, folder `.ecryptfs` has this files**

```
.wrapped-passphrase.recorded
wrapped-passphrase
Private.sig
Private.mnt
auto-umount 
auto-mount
```

I don't know how this folders and files was created, but I guess this files corresponding the older data which was on pc. Maybe the PC owner had done something wrong with the disk and the your data has changed for this.

But, How can I resolve this problem? What maybe has created or converted this files and folders?

Comment: What folder is this? Looks like /home and David's answer gets +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a user `soprano` encrypted their home directory with the "ecryptfs" encryption scheme.

You can read about it [on the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome).